# How to save formdata and this URL into the database .. I can upload the file to the cloudinary

Tags: laravel, file, cloudinary

Hiii , I have this formdata with few data and files. I want to store them into my database table.

this is my controller to store into the UserApplyJob model

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('resume');
        Cloudder::upload($file->getRealPath(), null, ['resource_type' => 'raw']); 
        $publicId = Cloudder::getPublicId();
        $url =Cloudder::show($publicId, ['resource_type' => 'raw']);

        $requestJob = UserApplyJob::create($request->all());


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not persisting it to the db. Try this at the end.

```
$requestJob->save();
```

Comment: Nope it still not working . I mean i can save the data into database but i cannot save the file as url ... i dont kno how to insert the url from cloudinary into database

Comment: what is the result from dd($url);

Comment: Looking at it, you are getting the url and setting it to a var but you're not doing anything with it. You need to be more explicit with creating your UserApplyJob model.

Answer (score 0):

This is from laravel 7.14

```
if($request->hasFile('cover_image'))
    {
        // Get the file with extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        //Get the file name
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get the ext
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //File name to store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    }
```

// Save the image to column

```
$blog->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
```